# JQuery / Microsoft Templating and Linking: Did they ever make these work together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, jquery-templates

[Scott Guthrie's blog about how they intended to do it.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/05/07/jquery-templates-and-data-linking-and-microsoft-contributing-to-jquery.aspx)

This appears to do nothing:

```
{{link fieldname}}
```

This appears to blow up:

```
${link fieldname}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The jQuery Templates and Data Linking were made [official jQuery plugins](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/04/jquery-templates-data-link-and-globalization-accepted-as-official-jquery-plugins.aspx).

Comment: JamieMThomas read the same thing I did, then made one himself http://github.com/jamiemthomas/jquery-datalink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He prefaces the section and example code with the following:

> Currently, we are working on an extension of the data linking proposal to support *declarative* data linking.

It's a planned extension/feature, but it's not in the first go-around.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any proposal that follows that syntax, not for linking anyway.  So no, they weren't meant to be combined line this (though you could run `.link()` after the elements are created...).

The [`.link()`](http://api.jquery.com/link/) and [`.unlink()`](http://api.jquery.com/unlink/) APIs can be [found here](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/data-link/).

Comment: Interesting.  Scott Guthrie mentioned Microsoft intended to combine both in that blog post near the end.  Just didn't know if they did anything with it.